# Why is ORDER BY id DESC not working in this line?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get `ORDER BY id DESC` to work in this line of php but I can't get it to work. It works without it though but they just display in the opposite order. Where should I position it?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%'");
```

**Update:**
I've updated the php with your suggestion that works now thanks. I've also updated it to mysqli as suggested, could this be structured better in anyway? It is working, just wondered if anyone has any improvements?

```
<?php
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $db = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >=1) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo"<div id='img_div'>";
                echo"<img src='images/".$row['image']."'>";
                echo"<h1>".$row['title']."</h1>";
                echo"<p>".$date = date('j F, Y', strtotime($row['date']))."</p>";
                echo"<p>".$row['link']."</p>";
            echo"</div>";    
        }
        //continue
    }else{
        echo "No Results";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please don't change the question completely, instead update the question and specify what changes you have made in the code(and related side-effects/further requirements), otherwise it would confuse future readers of SO.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong. `ORDER BY id DESC` should be placed **after** the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE title LIKE '%".$search."%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

---

**Sidenote(s):**

- Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).
- Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection attacks. Here's a good read on [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Hi @Rajdeep let me know what you think to the update thanks

Comment: @Jenny Good to see that you've switched to `MySQLi`, but your query is still susceptible to SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statement, as specified in my answer also. Start with this, [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)